# How to refresh/reload a slide out panel (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have this slide out panel with a comment form in it,  after user submitted the comment form, a "THANK YOU" will appear, the problem is, after I close the panel, and slide it out again for a second comment, the "THANK YOU" is still there! I was hoping to see a new unfilled comment form.

How do I have a fresh new original comment form to show up instead of the leftover from previous session?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("comment.pl", {
        comment:$("#comment").val(),
    },
    function(data,status){
      document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = "THANK YOU";
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the link to see the slide effect.</p>
    <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slide">Slide to Dialog Page</a>
  </div>
</div>  <!-- pageone -->
<div data-role="popup" data-dialog="true" id="pagetwo" >
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div id="div2">
    <b>Enter Comment</b>
    <br>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" data-role="none" rows=5 cols=30 onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){return false;}" onKeyDown="limitText2(this,100);" onKeyUp="limitText2(this,100);" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button data-inline="true"><font size=+2 color=#333333>Enter</font></button>
    <a href="#pageone" data-ajax="false">Go to Page One</a>
    </div> <!-- div2 -->
</div> <!-- ui-content -->
</div>  <!-- pagetwo -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont see a panel, I see a popup...with `data-dialog="true"`?! Pls go through demos and API of jQM first, sorry, but your code is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the content of the `div2`, it would be better to `.append` or `.show` an element. If we recreate the contents of div2 at runtime, we would need to reapply all the JS over this new code, in order to refresh it and make it able to post the data properly.

So, create a `#success` div that appears when the button is clicked:

```
...
 function(data,status){
      $('#success').show();
    });
...
```

There is an event that runs when an page transition animation is complete:

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $('div[data-role="main"]').live('pagehide',function(event, ui){
        //the 'pageHide' happens when the main is hidden
     $('#success').hide();

    });
 });
```

Comment: I did some show/hide test, but show does not refresh still, I enter some garbage and hide, then show, garbage still there, no refresh was done :(